# Android Dagger - Hilt ViewModel can't detect dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am facing runtime issue while running the application. I am new to dagger and hilt. Please help me out to resolve the issue.
Build Issue:

```
error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements AppController_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.ApiHelper is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.ApiHelperImpl(apiHelper)
      com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.ApiHelperImpl is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.AppModule.provideApiHelper(apiHelper)
      com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.ApiHelper is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.repositories.MainRepository(apiHelper)
      com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.repositories.MainRepository is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostViewModel(mainRepository)
      javax.inject.Provider<com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostViewModel> is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.ViewModelByDaggerFactory(viewModelProvider)
      com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.ViewModelByDaggerFactory<com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostViewModel> is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostFragment.viewModelFactory
      com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostFragment is injected at
          com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostFragment_GeneratedInjector.injectPostFragment(com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.ui.posts.PostFragment) [com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.AppController_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.AppController_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.AppController_HiltComponents.ActivityC ? com.hilt.hiltsampleproject.app.AppController_HiltComponents.FragmentC]
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.33-beta'

// Hilt Jetpack Integrations
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01'
```

PostFragment:

```
private val postViewModel: PostViewModel by viewModels()
```

PostViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel class PostViewModel @Inject constructor(private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel()
```

MainRespository:

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(
private val apiHelper: ApiHelper)
```

ApiHelper:

```
interface ApiHelper {
suspend fun getPosts(): Response<Posts>}
```

Comment: its hard to say the problem here does your fragment and your activity have entry point annotation ?

Comment: @rakeshkashyap yes it has.

Comment: I think the first two dependencies are enough, you don't need the androidx ones (you're mixing them). Try without those two.

Comment: I has same an issue. Hilt can not inject.

Comment: i would say you can either post a sample on git and i take a look or refer to https://github.com/rakesh1988/AndroidHackathonStarter/tree/hilt_path this gives u a good start

Comment: @rakeshkashyap I added the sample github. Please check the URL https://github.com/HemaSathiz/HiltSample/tree/master

Comment: @MartinMarconcini After removing still issue is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the github sample.

The issue is that you have a DependencyCycle:

```
class ApiHelperImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val apiHelper: ApiHelper
) : ApiHelper {
...
}
```

You're trying to Construct/Provide an instance of `ApiHelper` which also takes an instance of `ApiHelper` so, to construct the first ApiHelper, Hilt/Dagger have to construct the dependencies, so this ApiHelperImpl needs a ApiHelper... which needs a ApiHelper... which needs an ApiHelper... you hopefully get the idea :)